# How to create a list/array bean and pass it to the <list> tag as a reference in spring xml?

Tags: java, spring, xml-configuration

How to create a list/array bean and pass it to the `<list>` tag as a reference in spring xml?

I want to create a list with packages to scan:

```
<util:list id="hibernatePackagesToScan" value-type="java.lang.String">
    <value>com.example.models.MeasurementModel</value>
    <value>com.example.models.SensorModel</value>
</util:list>
```

And then pass it to hibernate:

```
<property name="packagesToScan">
  <list>
    <ref bean="hibernatePackagesToScan" />
  </list>
</property>
```

But unfortunatelly this is ending with exception:

> nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert
>   value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type
>   [java.lang.String] for property 'packagesToScan[0]': no matching
>   editors or conversion strategy found

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

```
<property name="packagesToScan" ref="hibernatePackagesToScan" />
```

I don't know why this didn't work before.

Answer (score 0):

*I don't know why this didn't work before.*

You were putting your list `hibernatePackagesToScan` as a element of the list `packagesToScan`.

See example to clarify:

```
    List<String> hibernatePackagesToScan = new ArrayList<>();

    hibernatePackagesToScan.add("package1");
    hibernatePackagesToScan.add("package2");

    // you ware trying to
    List<String> packagesToScan = new ArrayList<>();
    packagesToScan.put(hibernatePackagesToScan);

    // iso
    packagesToScan = hibernatePackagesToScan;
```